# rspec selenium test; variable url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec

I have a rails 3 app using rspec, and I'm writing a Selenium webdriver for it.

- the base url changes depending on the environment (local.website.com, demo.website.com ... etc)
- I want to be able to send a selenium file a variable of the url, and the file will run using the variable as the base url.

maybe something like this in the command line:

```
rspec spec/featur/selenium_file.rb base_url = "demo"
```

and in the Selenium file:

```
driver.navigate.to "#{base_url}.website.com" #which reads as demo.website.com
```

I'm not sure the best way to go about this. is there a way to run rspec with a variable specified like this? any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you make it an environment variable?

Comment: @TarynEast thanks for the point in the right direction! Yeah that's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was create a new environment variable. In my spec/spec_helper.rb file, i added this:

```
 ENV["BASE_URL"] ||= 'local'
```

then in the command line you can run spec and define the variable:

```
BASE_URL='demo' rspec spec/feature/selenium_file.rb
```

now that variable is usable in all the test files, so in selenium_file.rb you can run

```
puts ENV["BASE_URL"] #'demo'
```